# Jmeter for performance testing ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, selenium, jmeter

I have been given the task of using JMeter for performance testing for our web application.

Until now I was using selenium for UI testing and I have selenium test (testNG framework) ready, which I have executed using Selenium RC.

Is any migration from selenium to JMeter possible? Failing that, some helpful tutorials on JMeter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once upon a time, I use `jmeter` for load testing and had much trouble for just login to our asp.net web application. After lot of searching I write the blog [asp.net login testing with jmeter](http://sarwar026.blogspot.com/2013/04/aspnet-login-testing-with-jmeter.html).

If you are not using `asp.net`, then it may not be very helpful. In that case, you may visit [build web test plan using jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)

**Other Links:**

- http://jmeterperftest.blogspot.com/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html
- [Jmeter Summary Report analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381739/jmeter-summary-report-analysis)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are told to use JMeter.
Nevertheless, you could quickly evaluate other tools to check if another would not fit your needs.
I just tried [gatling](http://gatling-tool.org/) and could easily

- record a stress test by running manually my scenario in the browser
- customize the script to fit my needs
- run it with multiple configuration (number of users, length of the test etc.)

You might want to take a look : https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: out of purpose answer, user would have thr exact same problems with the tool you propose !

Comment: also all feature you mention exist in JMeter